# How to query DynamoDB table from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I have Lambda function that needs to query a table in DynamoDB.

The DynamoDB table was created with the following format :

```
              params = { 
                TableName: TableName,
                Item: {
                  'id' : {'S': someid},
                  'value' : {'S': 'somevalue'},
                  'requestfiltereddate' : {'N' : String(FilteredDate)},
                  'uri':{'S': uri},
                  'ip':{'S': ip},
                  'useragent':{'S': userAgent},
                }
              };
              
              await ddb.putItem(params).promise();
```

The table has a index on the column requestfiltereddate named : requestfiltereddate-index.

then I'm trying to query the same table with the following code :

```
              params = {
                    TableName: 'MyTable',
                    IndexName: "requestfiltereddate-index",
                    KeyConditionExpression: "requestfiltereddate = :date1",
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {":date1": {"N": String(Date.now())}},
                    ProjectionExpression: "id"
                };                                            
              
               var results = await ddb.query(params).promise();
```

When testing the function, I'm not getting any answer. Instead I'm getting a generic error with no meaning or details to investigate:

```
    Response
    {
      "errorMessage": "2023-01-06T01:48:52.156Z 555e0a58-e021-4ae2-b431-xxxxxxx Task timed out after 1.05 seconds"
    }

    Function Logs
    START RequestId: 555e0a58-e021-4ae2-b431-xxxxxxxxxxxxx Version: $LATEST
    2023-01-06T01:48:52.156Z 555e0a58-e021-4ae2-b431-xxxxxxxxxxxxx Task timed out after 1.05 seconds

    END RequestId: 555e0a58-e021-4ae2-b431-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    REPORT RequestId: 555e0a58-e021-4ae2-b431-xxxxxxxxxxxxx Duration: 1054.53 ms    Billed Duration: 1000 ms    Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 26 MB

    Request ID
    555e0a58-e021-4ae2-b431-xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried to increase lambda function timeout and execute the query again? Does error persist?

Comment: Plus its much better to use Dynamodb document client, you dont have to mention data types it abstracts that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.WriteItem.html

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Thanks for your comment. I didn't try to increase lambda timout because the table has only one element and I'm trying to query based on a field that has an index. So i'm expecting it to be instantaneous. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be instantaneous, are you sure your query is right, I think date.now returns the current date and time and probably this is the error point, could you replace it with the existing field value just to verify

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you're getting shows that your Lambda function reached its timeout (after 1.05s) and was terminated before it finished running.

You can try increasing the function timeout in the AWS Lambda Console to a larger value to give the Lambda function more time to finish running (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-function-common.html#configuration-timeout-console).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't try to increase lambda timout because the table has only one element and I'm trying to query based on a field that has an index. So i'm expecting it to be instantaneous. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Even with one element, it has to set up the database connection, which could take some time. To be sure that the problem is actually because the connection is timing out, you can increase the time out of the Lambda and see if the code executes successfully to rule out other sources of error